# Is it possible to check if a document has unique permissions using SP2010 Client Object Model

Tags: development, permissions, client-object-model, document

I have a 2010 site that has many documents in many different folders. I believe a number of them have broken permission inheritence. Is there a way i can code a C# console app to utilise client object model, go through my libraries and check if a document has unique permissions?

I have done the standard google, checked msdn and nothing turns up. It seems to be a unique problem.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually yes it is (details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurableobject.hasuniqueroleassignments(v=office.14).aspx). One important note though - simple Load statement with a ListItemCollection parameter (i.e. ctx.Load(lic)) does not load 4 properties of ListItem by default when you return list items:  DisplayName, EffectiveBasePermissions, HasUniqueRoleAssignments, and RoleAssignments.  If you tried to reference them in your code, you will get a Property not initialized error.

To get beyond that you need to specifically ask to have them included when you define your query using, by example the IncludeWithDefaultProperties

```
function retrieveProperties () {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('/sites/TestWebs/TestWeb1');
    this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

    clientContext.load(oWebsite, 'Title', 'HasUniqueRoleAssignments');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Title: ' + oWebsite.get_title() + 
    '\nUnique role assignments: ' + oWebsite.get_hasUniqueRoleAssignments());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: I've updated the response with an example straight from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee534974(v=office.14).aspx